# Exposing docker ports on native globally unique IPv6

Tags: docker, networking, ipv6, docker-network

Let me start by acknowledging my setup is not a normal use case, I want to be able to run multiple microservices on my home pi so I've jammed docker for Arch64 onto my raspberry pi.

My ISP provides native IPv6 so **I want each container to have a public IPv6 address** (it's then up to me to decide on my home firewall if this is publicly available). I understand the concept of having multiple IPv4 addresses assigned to a NIC and linking exposing these directly discussed here https://forums.docker.com/t/public-accessible-ip-in-container-like-bridge-network-in-virtualbox/3668. Almost all the documentation I've read presumes running on ISP-provided IPv4, I've followed the below two guides from docker.
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/ https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/
resulting in my /etc/docker/daemon.json  looking something like the following:

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2a02:a210:1234::/64",
  "default-gateway-v6": "2a02:a210:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234"
}
```

when I try to change things inside /etc/default/docker the docker service fails to start.

I've also created a new network called publicv6 which (you guessed it) has/80 of my public v6 addresses (this still leaves 48 bits for the Mac address and IPv6 EUI-64).

running docker inspect: (have obscured any numbers with 1234)

```
"NetworkMode": "publicv6",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "1234",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/2134",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "publicv6": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv6Address": "2a02:a210:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "1234"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "1234",
                    "EndpointID": "1234",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.20.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "2a02:a210:1234:1234:1234::1234",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "2a02:a210:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 80,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
```

see also: docker network inspect publicv6:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "publicv6",
        "Id": "1234",
        "Created": "2021-02-25T16:09:59.041001102Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": true,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                },
                {
                    "Subnet": "2a02:a210:1234:1234:1234::/80",
                    "Gateway": "2a02:a210:1234:1234:1234::1"
                }
            ]
        },
```

I then run a docker container:

```
docker run -d --name apachephp --net=publicv6 --ip6 2a02:a210:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234  -p 80:80
```

but when I check it still seems that the containers are running Natted IPv4 and aren't assessable on any device other than the host. what am I missing?

as a side note the IP address being used for the gateway in publicv6 shows when running 'ip a' on the host:

```
25: br-143673f7eb03: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:f9:aa:b1:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-143673f7eb03
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a02:a210:1234:1234:1234::1/80 scope global
```

I also ran a few random commands from google on my host such as:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding (returned 1)

does anyone have any ideas (asides from using the NAT IPv4 internally) to get each container to have a public ipv6 address

Comment: "_I've also created a new network called publicv6 which (you guessed it) has a /80 of my public v6 addresses (this still leaves 48 bits for the Mac address and IPv6 EUI-64)._" You really need to use `/64` networks, otherwise you will break some IPv6 features. Also, your IPv6 gateway will be the link-local address of the router, and all IPv6 interfaces need a link-local address. You cannot simply use "IPv4 thinking" to try to apply IPv6 to something. For example, IPv6 requires the router to send RAs, and the host uses that to determine if it is stateful configuration or not.

Comment: Hi @Ron, 
can you add any more detail to your answer, I changed the gateway to the link local address of my router, now the docker service won't start.
`Mar 02 21:15:27 pi dockerd[3712]: failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: auxiliary address: (DefaultGatewayIPv6:fe80::1a35:d1ff:fef7:7730) must belong to the master pool: 2a02:a210:` 
 /80 seems perfectly valid from everything I've read, can you explain / source why not? Can you be more specific on the Docker configuration required? what network should I use?

Comment: I did not post an answer, just a comment. I have [an answer for the IPv6 /64 network size](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/34172/8499). The gateway (router) sends RAs that tell the hosts how they should be configured, and the RAs contain the gateway address, which will be a link-local address. You cannot simply take the way IPv4 works and assign IPv6 addressing the same way.